# Автоматический вывод мета-тегов

Tags: php

Нужно что бы в мета-теги делалась запись по типу: Подобрать товар для такого то авто. То есть Строка "подобрать товар для" статичная и не меняется, а строка "такого то авто" меняется в зависимости от страницы. На разных страницах разные заголовки и нужно что бы из этих заголовков и бралось значение. Такой код не походит:

```
   <?php
  function create_meta {

      $meta1 = '<h1(.*(class="(?P<class>.+)"?).*|)>(?P<text>[^<]+)<\/h1>';
      $meta_result ='Подобрать товар для'.$meta1;

      return $meta_result;

   }

 ?>
```

Comment: Ну так у вас где-то в коде формируется заголовок. Передайте это значение ещё и в мету. В чём сложность?

Comment: Нашел в бд таблицу категорий, думаю правильнее будет сделать через sql запросы. Создал тему, посмотрите - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/942765/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-sql-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85

Comment: Не нужно создавать новый вопрос. Достаточно отредактировать текущий, нажав на кнопку "править"

Comment: Согласен абсолютно.