# Добавление в таблицу SQL данных

Tags: php

Есть таблица категороий jos_categories, в этой таблице есть поле title, оно на всех категориях заполнено, есть еще одно поле metadesc, оно не заполнено. Нужно сделать скрипт который добавит значение title в metadesc и допишет в начале строку. Пока застопорился на этом этапе:

```
      <?php  

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT title FROM jos_categories";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$query2 = "SELECT DISTINCT metadesc FROM jos_categories";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) ;



 while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                            {
                            $title = $row['title']; 

                            };
$meta_create = "INSERT INTO $query2 VALUES $title"



?>
```

Comment: `UPDATE jos_categories SET metadesc=title`

Comment: $meta_create = "UPDATE jos_categories SET metadesc=title" , так?

Comment: Так не работает, к сожалению.

Comment: Без текста ошибки - это пустые слова

Comment: Такая запись не срабатывает - не заносится запись в базу

Comment: metadesc=0 сделал, тоже не появилось значение почему то, может это поле не принимать значения?

Comment: Есть варианты почему не работает?

Comment: Надо не гадать, а после выполнения запроса mysql_query вывести ошибки, если они вдруг были. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-error.php И еще по этой ссылке обратите внимание на предупреждение, что функции которыми вы пользуетесь уже 10 лет не поддерживаются и скоро их в языке вообще не будет и все ваши программы перестанут работать